# JPA: Generate a code based on the Auto-incremented id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have and entity with two fields an id and a code as so...

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Basic
@Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
private String code;
```

What I would like is to do is, to generate the code based on the Auto-incremented id (Using Mysql as DB).

Is there a way without using a table to generate keys for the code column. 
i.e

- id = 1 code is M-000-1
- id = 2 code is  M-000-2 etc..

The only way I have managed to do this is using the script below. Which I am not so sure is the correct way.

```
getEntityManager().persist(myEntity);
getEntityManager().flush();
myEntity.setCode(myEntity.getCode()+myEntity.getId());
getEntityManager().merge(myEntity);
```

Thanks in advance!
Dimitri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine. You can perhaps move it to a `@PostPersist` handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom sequence generator using the `@GenericGenerator` annotation. This is specific to Hibernate, but is known to work in JPA.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="custom-code-generator")
@GenericGenerator(name="custom-code-generator", strategy = "classname-of-generator",
parameters={...annotated parameters like the sequence name can be specified here ...})
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

The strategy is to be implemented in a class that implements the [`PersistentIdentifierGenerator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/PersistentIdentifierGenerator.html) interface, and as noted in the API documentation, custom generators would also implement the [`Configurable`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/Configurable.html) interface to allow for configuration of the generator.

Using the `@PostPersist` annotation will also work, in that the Id is not flushed to the database until the EntityManager is flushed or if the transaction associated with the EntityManager is committed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with `@PostPersist`:

```
class EntityClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @PostPersist
    public void generateCode() {
        code = ("M-000-" + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This dosn't feel like a good way to do it. What happens when you do a merge? Then you will have different id in DB and persistance layer..

Comment: Since the ID is the primary key, it will be generated one time, at persist time; afterwards, it will not change. Could you give more details about your merge case?

Comment: My apologize, I have misunderstood the original question(I thought the id in the DB would be the code). I now agree with your solution. Sorry for taking up your time.